# UITableView cell's disappear when table is left then returned to

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a table view. i can add and delete cells. lest say i add 5. When i leave the table view ( switch views), and return to the table view, the cells are gone. Why is this happening? Also, how could i fix this? Thanks!

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
     {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

         stepper = [[UIStepper alloc]init];
         [stepper setFrame:CGRectMake(216, 22, 100, 30)];
         NSLog(@"the stepper is %@", stepper);
         [cell addSubview:stepper];

         cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
         [cellLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(65, 22, 27, 27)];
         [cellLabel setText:@"1"];
         [cell.contentView addSubview:cellLabel];
    } 
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    cell.imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
   // cell.textLabel.text = [cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([cell.imageView.image  isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle5.png"]]) {
        [cellLabel setFrame:CGRectMake (175, 22, 30, 30)];
    }
    if ([cell.imageView.image  isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle4.png"]]) {
        [cellLabel setFrame:CGRectMake (150, 22, 30, 30)];
    }
    if ([cell.imageView.image  isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle3.png"]]) {
        [cellLabel setFrame:CGRectMake (120, 22, 30, 30)];
    }
    if ([cell.imageView.image  isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle2.png"]]) {
        [cellLabel setFrame:CGRectMake (90, 22, 30, 30)];
    }
return cell;
}
```

**NumberOfRows**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [cells count];
}
```

**CommitEditingStyle:**

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
 forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [[self cells] removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [[self imageArray]removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
        [[self myTableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code that you are using? The text of this question does not give enough info to answer your question meaningfully.

Comment: ill add the cellForRow! Is that the code you would like?

Comment: When you add cell, have you add the corresponding new data into your datasource?

Comment: @Nevin what do you mean by add it to my dataSource?

Comment: @iProRage it's a good start. Could you please show the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method (I assume that you return `imageArray.count` there), and your `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: okay, ill post those right now! Thank you very much for the help too! :D

Comment: Do the contents of `[self cells]` get cleared when you leave the view controller? (Do you push a *new* view controller every time you bring it onto the screen?)

Comment: @iProRage: dasblinkenlight has posted the solution already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your code of the `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` is missing the part of what to do on insertion:

```
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    [[self imageArray] insertObject:... atIndex:...];
}
```

Without this code, your `imageArray` has only the old objects when you switch away and come back.
You should also initiate reload of the data from the model at the end of the method:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: okay, i understand, But what should i put for the `insertObject` part of that method? Because for the delete style, i just put `[[self imageArray]removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];` and i dont specify what to remove, so im not too sure what to insert!

Comment: by the way, thank you for the help! I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: @iProRage I do not know exactly what objects you keep in your model, but from your deletion code it looks like you have two "parallel" arrays going on: `imageArray` and `cells`. I couldn't find other uses of `cells` outside the `numberOfRowsInSection` method, but it looks like the `imageArray` should get one of four images (paddle2.png through paddle5.png); I do not know which one - perhaps the one that you use by default.